# How to get an ink! contract's AccountId in unit tests?

Tags: ink, unit-tests, contracts

From what I understand from the docs, every contract gets its own AccountId. But in the [contract-transfer](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/contract-transfer/lib.rs) tests, I'm getting the same AccountId from both `accounts.alice` and `contract_id()`.

I modified the contract to return its AccountId using `self.env().account_id()`, but it still returns Alice's AccountId.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The testing Engine is still limited in some capabilities: It is correct that a Smart Contract obtains its own `AccountId`, but I doubt that this is currently reflected by the testing Engine, since it currently doesn't simulate the instantiation of a Smart Contract, which would assign an `AccountId` to the contract.

Therefore `self.env().account_id()` currently returns the callee's AccountId, which is manually set by calling `ink_env::test::set_callee::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>(account_id)`. If you want to test it, you need to configure an `AccountId` for your Smart Contract first. I added a test in my example [here](https://github.com/achimcc/contract_get_account_id/blob/main/lib.rs#L125-L137).

I added a function `getId()` to the `contract-transfer` example [here](https://github.com/achimcc/contract_get_account_id/blob/main/lib.rs).

After starting Substrate contracts node locally (version substrate-contracts-node 0.11.0-bb0cd97-x86_64-linux-gnu) with `substrate-contracts-node --dev --tmp`, and connecting it with the [contracts UI](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/), I can call the function to obtain the contracts `AccountId`, which is different from Alice's `AccountId`:

[image]

So it indeed returns the Smart Contracts `AccountId` when deplyed on the Substrate Node.

Comment: I basically created a function in the contract that returns `self.env().account_id()` . The issue is only in the contract's unit tests, it works properly in contracts-ui.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem! I updated my answer above.